# How to elude using eval set -- for parsing arguments?

Tags: bash

While studying the parsing of arguments by **bash** scripts using **getopt**, I have almost everywhere watched the use of this construction: `eval set -- "$SOMETHING_PARSED"`. For example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash?page=1&tab=scoredesc#tab-top) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483119/an-example-of-how-to-use-getopts-in-bash). Since I am going to post my working scripts in the future for free access, I would like not to leave such a hole for users. Are there any ways to avoid this?

It is described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/675320/524604) that depending on the version of **getopt**, you can do without `eval`. But at least it is not my case. **getopt** gives a string like this: `' -j --version= '\''1'\'' --number= '\''2'\'' -- '\''2C_IA/GBCs_out/nohope_2C_IA_off. xml'\'''`. & `set` assigns it completely to `$1`.

Comment: I suggest you read that answer again, especially this: "which happily breaks arguments that contain whitespace or look like globs" - that's an actual hole you get from *not* using eval, as opposed to whatever imaginary hole you think you're leaving for users by using eval.

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of `getopt` (the implementation from `util-linux` or `busybox` at least when used the non-traditional way) is that it outputs shell code intended to be evaluated. `getopt` does quote the characters that are special in the shell syntax in option arguments¹ making it safe to use there in Bourne-like shells other than `yash`².

With the POSIX `sh` language, it's the easiest way that a command may return an arbitrary list of strings for the shell.

`getopt` implementations that don't support that modus operandi (like the original `getopt` which relies on using the split+glob operator instead) are broken by design as they can't return arbitrary lists.

If you don't want to use `eval` for some reason, but switching to `zsh` is an option, you can use instead:

```
argv=( "${(@XQ)${(z)$(getopt...)}}" ) || exit
```

Where the `z` parameter expansion flag does the tokenising based on shell quoting syntax (`zsh` quoting syntax, but `getopt` only uses single quotes for quoting) `Q` removes the quotes and `X` complains in case of syntax error.

The only advantage is that if `getopt` has been replaced by some evil command that outputs evil code, it would not be run, but then again, while *evil guy* is at replacing `getopt`, they might as well get it to *run* that evil code itself rather than outputting it for you to eval it.

It's possible for a command to communicate an arbitrary list of strings to `bash` 4.4+ (as opposed to `sh`) if you send it NUL-delimited, by reading its output into an array with:

```
readarray -td '' array < <(cmd) || exit # readarray failed.
wait "$!" || exit # cmd failed
set -- "${array[@]}"
```

Or same with `zsh`:

```
argv=( "${(0@)$(cmd)}" ) || exit
argv[-1]=() # remove the empty trailing argument caused by the terminating NUL
```

So one could in theory implement a `getopt` that uses that modus operandi.

Note that `getopt` is not the only utility that expects you do evaluate its output, see also:

```
eval "$(dbus-launch --sh-syntax)"
eval "$(dpkg-architecture -u)"
eval "set $(git rev-parse --sq --prefix "$prefix" -- "$@")"
eval "$(lesspipe)"
eval "$(xz --robot --version)"
eval "$(resize)"
eval "$(dircolors)"
```

Where it's used to modify the environment of the shell.

See also all those that can be used to save the current state and restore later:

```
aliases=$(alias -L) # zsh
aliases=$(alias -p) # ksh/bash
options=$(set +o)
locale=$(locale)
```

To restore as `eval "$aliases"`, `eval "$options"`...

Alternatives to `getopt` for parsing options that don't involve using `eval`:

- The standard `getopts` builtin, though except in `ksh93`³, that only supports single letter options.
- `zsh`'s `zparseopts`³
- My [`getopts_long`](https://github.com/stephane-chazelas/misc-scripts/blob/master/getopts_long.sh) POSIX `sh` function

---

<sup>¹ not in option names though at least with version 2.38 which could be seen as a bug, though it should be fine as long as you don't pick silly names for your script's options</sup>

<sup>² current versions of `yash` (as of June 2022) can only deal with valid text so would choke anyway on arguments that cannot be decoded as text in the current locale</sup>

<sup>³ neither ksh93's `getopts` nor zsh's `zparseopts` parse the option the same way as GNU `getopt_long()` (or `util-linux` `getopt`). In particular, they don't support abbreviating long options.</sup>