# How to properly parse a quoted arg-list string in a shell script?

Tags: shell-script, quoting, posix, arguments

###### Summary

How to convert a single string `a "b" 'c d' $'e\nf'` into separate arguments, respecting quotes and preserving whitespaces and newlines?

###### Question

I'm trying to read and process the output of a script that exports value lists, one per line, in form of quoted strings (as created by `printf %q`). The values within a list are space-separated, may be quoted, may include spaces and newlines, and are of unknown count.

Example: `a "b" 'c d' $'e\nf'`

I'm looking for a way to restore the values in a POSIX shell script and handle them as arguments to a shell function.

Desired solutions, in descending priority:

1. POSIX shell commands and core utilities like `xargs`, `printf` and the like; no `eval`
2. Bash
3. A full-blown programming language like perl

###### Skeleton for the shell script `process.sh`:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
set -eu

process() {
  printf '>%s<\n' "${@}"
}

main() {
  value_list="${1}"
  # split value list here and set positional parameters
  set -- ???
  process "${@}"
}

main "${@}"
```

###### Desired behaviour

```bsh
$ process.sh "a \"b\" 'c d' $'e\nf'"
>a<
>b<
>c d<
>e
f<
```

###### What happened so far

- I tried different combinations of `printf` (incl. `%q`), `xargs`, `while read` loops, changing `IFS`, separation of args with a `null` byte, subshell invocations, heredocs.
- `xargs` allows unquoting, but only for spaces, not for newlines, and only without argument `-d`.
- A `while read` loop can parse args, but does not allow to call a shell function when input is read from a pipe

Comment: Similar to this one from a week ago: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/676249/170373 Stéphane's answer there has a solution using zsh.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on a [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/677406/how-to-properly-parse-a-quoted-arg-list-string-in-a-shell-script#comment1279384_677406) by [ilkkachu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/170373/ilkkachu) and uses `zsh`.

###### Shell script `process.sh`:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
set -eu
export script="$(readlink -f "${0}")"

split() {
  zsh -c 'printf "%s\0" "${(Q@)${(z)1}}"' "${script}/split" "${@}"
}

process() {
  printf '>%s<\n' "${@}"
}

main() {
  value_list="${1}"
  split "${value_list}" | xargs -0 sh -c 'init() { . "${script}"; } && init && process "${@}"' "${script}/main"
}

[ "${#}" -eq 0 ] || main "${@}"
```

###### Benefits

- It works

###### Drawbacks

- Script must be sourced to call `process()` form `xargs`, a little awkward wrapped in a function to strip the arguments and prevent an endless loop
- Requirement for `zsh`

Answer (score 0):

A simplified variant of [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/677440/501168) `zsh`-based answer:

```bsh
#!/bin/zsh
set -eu

process() {
  printf '>%s<\n' "${@}"
}

main() {
  value_list="${1}"
  process "${(Q@)${(z)value_list}}"
}

main "${@}"
```

###### Benefits

- It works

###### Drawbacks

- Requirement for zsh